# canvasjs Charts takes too much time to render

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts

through  WebSocket fetching the data from The developers.binary but canvasjs is rendering to the charts taking too much time but I saw that a lot of charts all are rendering normally not taking much time. I want to know that why it happens

what should I do to render the charts quickly?
I need to visible the charts quickly
is it taking time to the API call or I've mistaken anything?

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {

  var ws, b, rnd, spot, time, dps, xd, digit, cnt, random, id, lng, str, chart, xVal, yVal, mType, mColor, rndMenu;
  ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=3738&l=" + lng);

  str = ["R_100", "R_10", "R_25", "R_50", "R_75", "RDBEAR", "RDBULL"];
  dps = [];
  time = [0];
  spot = [0];
  digit = [0];
  mType = "none";
  mColor = "#32cd32";
  lng = "EN";
  xVal = 0;
  yVal = 0;
  cnt = 20;

  rndMenu = document.querySelectorAll('div.menu > span');


  function toggleDigit(d, m) {

    var nameClass = document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + d + ")").className;
    if (nameClass != "digits_moved_" + m) {
      document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + d + ")").classList.remove(nameClass);
      document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + d + ")").classList.add("digits_moved_" + m);
    }

  }

  function rndGet() {

    random = document.querySelector("body > div.menu > span.menu-active").title;

    rnd = "R_10";
    xd = 3;
  }

  rndGet();



  ws.onopen = function(evt) {


    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      ticks: rnd
    }));

  };

  ws.onmessage = function(msg) {

    b = JSON.parse(msg.data);



    if (b.tick) {



      if (b.echo_req.ticks == rnd) {
        id = b.tick.id;
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
          ticks_history: rnd,
          end: "latest",
          start: 1,
          style: "ticks",
          count: cnt + 1
        }));


      } else {

        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
          forget: id
        }));
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
          forget_all: "ticks"
        }));
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
          ticks: rnd
        }));
      };

    };

    if (b.history) {

      if (b.echo_req.ticks_history == rnd) {



        for (var i = 0; i < cnt + 1; i++) {

          time[i] = b.history.times[cnt - i];
          spot[i] = b.history.prices[cnt - i];
          spot[i] = Number(spot[i]).toFixed(xd);
          digit[i] = spot[i].slice(-1);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < cnt + 1; i++) {


          xVal = new Date(time[i] * 1000);
          yVal = parseFloat(spot[i]);

          if (i == 0) mType = "circle";
          else mType = "none";

          if (yVal == Math.max.apply(null, spot)) {

            mColor = "#29abe2";
            mType = "circle";
          } else if (yVal == Math.min.apply(null, spot)) {
            mColor = "#c03";
            mType = "circle";
          } else {
            mColor = "#32cd32";
          }

          dps.push({
            x: xVal,
            y: yVal,
            markerType: mType,
            markerColor: mColor,
            markerBorderColor: "#ccc"
          });

        }




        chart.render()
        spot.reverse();
        digit.reverse();

        for (var i = 1; i < cnt + 1; i++) {

          document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + i + ")").innerHTML = digit[i];

          if (spot[i - 1] < spot[i]) {

            toggleDigit(i, "up");
          } else if (spot[i - 1] > spot[i]) {
            toggleDigit(i, "down");
          } else if (spot[i - 1] == spot[i] && i - 1 > 0) {
            if (document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + (i - 1) + ")").className == "digits_moved_up") {
              toggleDigit(i, "up");
            } else if (document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + (i - 1) + ")").className == "digits_moved_down") {
              toggleDigit(i, "down");
            }

          }

        }

      };

    };


  };



  chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: false,
    theme: "light2",
    title: {
      titleFontSize: 0,
      text: ""
    },
    toolTip: {
      enabled: true,
      animationEnabled: true,
      borderColor: "#ccc",
      borderThickness: 1,
      fontColor: "#000",
      content: "{y}"
    },
    axisX: {
      includeZero: false,
      titleFontSize: 0,
      labelFontSize: 0,
      gridThickness: 0,
      tickLength: 0,
      lineThickness: 0
    },
    axisY: {
      includeZero: false,
      titleFontSize: 0,
      labelFontSize: 0,
      gridThickness: 0,
      tickLength: 0,
      lineThickness: 0
    },
    data: [{
      type: "spline",
      lineColor: "#ccc",
      lineThickness: 2,
      markerType: "none",
      markerSize: 5,
      markerBorderThickness: 0,
      dataPoints: dps
    }],

  });



  e.preventDefault()
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Asim chart</title>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 34px;
    }
    
    .menu {
      margin-bottom: 16px;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .menu span {
      padding: 3px 0;
      flex-basis: auto;
      flex-grow: 1;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #666666;
    }
    
    .menu span:hover {
      background: #191919;
    }
    
    span.menu-active {
      background: #191919;
    }
    
    .digits {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .disclaimer {
      font-size: 11px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
      color: #707070;
    }
    
    .digits span {
      padding: 25px 0;
      flex-basis: auto;
      flex-grow: 1;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 24px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .digits_moved_down {
      background-color: #c03;
    }
    
    .digits_moved_up {
      background-color: #29abe2;
    }
    
    .chartContainer {
      min-height: 350px;
      min-width: 50px;
    }
  </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="EN">
  <h1>charts</h1>
  <h3>charts difference</h3>
  <div class="menu">
    <span class="" title="R_100">100</span>
    <span class="menu-active" title="R_10">10</span>
    <span class="" title="R_25">25</span>
    <span class="" title="R_50">50</span>
    <span class="" title="R_75">75</span>
    <span class="" title="RDBEAR">ODD/EVEN</span>
    <span class="" title="RDBULL">MATCH/DIFFERS</span>
  </div>
  <p>Charts might take up to 30 secs to load.. please wait...</p>
  <div id="digits" class="digits">
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
    <span class="_"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="chartContainer" id="chartContainer"></div>





  <div class="disclaimer">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chart is getting rendered within 20-30 milliseconds. However,  API call & the response seems to be taking 3-5 secs. Below is the code showcasing the time taken:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
  var timeNow;
  var ws, b, rnd, spot, time, dps, xd, digit, cnt, random, id, lng, str, chart, xVal, yVal, mType, mColor, rndMenu;
  ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=3738&l=" + lng);

  str = ["R_100", "R_10", "R_25", "R_50", "R_75", "RDBEAR", "RDBULL"];
  dps = [];
  time = [0];
  spot = [0];
  digit = [0];
  mType = "none";
  mColor = "#32cd32";
  lng = "EN";
  xVal = 0;
  yVal = 0;
  cnt = 20;

  rndMenu = document.querySelectorAll('div.menu > span');

  function toggleDigit(d, m) {
    var nameClass = document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + d + ")").className;
    if (nameClass != "digits_moved_" + m) {
      document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + d + ")").classList.remove(nameClass);
      document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + d + ")").classList.add("digits_moved_" + m);
    }
  }

  function rndGet() {
    random = document.querySelector("body > div.menu > span.menu-active").title;
    rnd = "R_10";
    xd = 3;
  }
  rndGet();

  ws.onopen = function (evt) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
      ticks: rnd
    }));

  };

  ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
    b = JSON.parse(msg.data);
    if (b.tick) {
      if (b.echo_req.ticks == rnd) {
        id = b.tick.id;
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
          ticks_history: rnd,
          end: "latest",
          start: 1,
          style: "ticks",
          count: cnt + 1
        }));
      } else {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
          forget: id
        }));
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
          forget_all: "ticks"
        }));
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
          ticks: rnd
        }));
      };
    };

    if (b.history) {
      if (b.echo_req.ticks_history == rnd) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cnt + 1; i++) {
          time[i] = b.history.times[cnt - i];
          spot[i] = b.history.prices[cnt - i];
          spot[i] = Number(spot[i]).toFixed(xd);
          digit[i] = spot[i].slice(-1);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < cnt + 1; i++) {
          xVal = new Date(time[i] * 1000);
          yVal = parseFloat(spot[i]);

          if (i == 0) mType = "circle";
          else mType = "none";

          if (yVal == Math.max.apply(null, spot)) {

            mColor = "#29abe2";
            mType = "circle";
          } else if (yVal == Math.min.apply(null, spot)) {
            mColor = "#c03";
            mType = "circle";
          } else {
            mColor = "#32cd32";
          }

          dps.push({
            x: xVal,
            y: yVal,
            markerType: mType,
            markerColor: mColor,
            markerBorderColor: "#ccc"
          });
        }

        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        chart.render();
        console.log("Chart rendered in: ", new Date().getTime() - startTime + "ms");
        spot.reverse();
        digit.reverse();

        for (var i = 1; i < cnt + 1; i++) {
          document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + i + ")").innerHTML = digit[i];
          if (spot[i - 1] < spot[i]) {

            toggleDigit(i, "up");
          } else if (spot[i - 1] > spot[i]) {
            toggleDigit(i, "down");
          } else if (spot[i - 1] == spot[i] && i - 1 > 0) {
            if (document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + (i - 1) + ")").className == "digits_moved_up") {
              toggleDigit(i, "up");
            } else if (document.querySelector("#digits > span:nth-child(" + (i - 1) + ")").className == "digits_moved_down") {
              toggleDigit(i, "down");
            }
          }
        }
      };
    };
  };

  chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: false,
    theme: "light2",
    title: {
      titleFontSize: 0,
      text: ""
    },
    toolTip: {
      enabled: true,
      animationEnabled: true,
      borderColor: "#ccc",
      borderThickness: 1,
      fontColor: "#000",
      content: "{y}"
    },
    axisX: {
      includeZero: false,
      titleFontSize: 0,
      labelFontSize: 0,
      gridThickness: 0,
      tickLength: 0,
      lineThickness: 0
    },
    axisY: {
      includeZero: false,
      titleFontSize: 0,
      labelFontSize: 0,
      gridThickness: 0,
      tickLength: 0,
      lineThickness: 0
    },
    data: [{
      type: "spline",
      lineColor: "#ccc",
      lineThickness: 2,
      markerType: "none",
      markerSize: 5,
      markerBorderThickness: 0,
      dataPoints: dps
    }]
  });

  e.preventDefault()
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Asim chart</title>
    <style>
      body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
      }
      h1 {
      font-size: 34px;
      }
      .menu {
      margin-bottom: 16px;
      display: flex;
      }
      .menu span {
      padding: 3px 0;
      flex-basis: auto;
      flex-grow: 1;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #666666;
      }
      .menu span:hover {
      background: #191919;
      }
      span.menu-active {
      background: #191919;
      }
      .digits {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      display: flex;
      }
      .disclaimer {
      font-size: 11px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
      color: #707070;
      }
      .digits span {
      padding: 25px 0;
      flex-basis: auto;
      flex-grow: 1;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 24px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      color: #fff;
      }
      .digits_moved_down {
      background-color: #c03;
      }
      .digits_moved_up {
      background-color: #29abe2;
      }
      .chartContainer {
      min-height: 350px;
      min-width: 50px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="EN">
    <h1>charts</h1>
    <h3>charts difference</h3>
    <div class="menu">
      <span class="" title="R_100">100</span>
      <span class="menu-active" title="R_10">10</span>
      <span class="" title="R_25">25</span>
      <span class="" title="R_50">50</span>
      <span class="" title="R_75">75</span>
      <span class="" title="RDBEAR">ODD/EVEN</span>
      <span class="" title="RDBULL">MATCH/DIFFERS</span>
    </div>
    <p>Charts might take up to 30 secs to load.. please wait...</p>
    <div id="digits" class="digits">
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
      <span class="_"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="chartContainer" id="chartContainer"></div>
    <div class="disclaimer">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please Below the link I want to like this. The charts is showing data regularly not taking much time to render the data 
https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/
can I reduce the time to Chart get rendered quickly is it possible?
why it take too much time to render its problem for the API or anything else?